# Can't seem to solve $e^{3e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}}$ into cartesian form

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I tried to use the code to format the equations correctly but I can't seem to make it work so I'm just going to type normally.
So I have a question on $e^{3e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}}}$. I was going to do it the normal way such that it equals to $\cos(3e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}})+i\sin(3e^{\frac{i\pi}{3}})$, but its not working since I can't exponentially multiply it. Are there any other methods that I can use?

Comment: $e^{ix} = \cos x+i\sin x$ is useful for real values of $x$. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1):

Note that
$$
3e^{\frac{\pi }{3}i}  = \frac{3}{2} + \frac{{3\sqrt 3 }}{2}i.
$$
Thus,
$$
e^{3e^{\frac{\pi }{3}i} }  = e^{\frac{3}{2}} e^{\frac{{3\sqrt 3 }}{2}i}  = e^{\frac{3}{2}} \cos \left( {\frac{{3\sqrt 3 }}{2}} \right) + ie^{\frac{3}{2}} \sin \left( {\frac{{3\sqrt 3 }}{2}} \right).
$$